# Image from Wikipedia main page is now showing in window form

Tags: c#, json, exception, deserialization, wikipedia-api

I try to get the first image from wikipedia api. I wrote the following C# code to retrieve the source from Thumbnail. But whenever I run the code it shows exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll Additional information: Unexpected
>   character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0,
>   position 0.

My code is as follows

```
     public class Thumbnail
        {
            public string source { get; set; }
            public int width { get; set; }
            public int height { get; set; }
        }

        public class Pageval
        {
            public int pageid { get; set; }
            public int ns { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
            public string pageimage { get; set; }
        }



        public class Query
        {
            public Dictionary<string, Pageval> pages { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public string batchcomplete { get; set; }
            public Query query { get; set; }
        }
        class Class1
        {


            public static PictureBox Image1 = new PictureBox();
            public static Label Image1_title = new Label();

            public static void Load_Image(string name1, string LocationName)
            {
                var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
                string Imagefolder = Path.Combine(startPath, "Image");
                string subImageFolder = Path.Combine(Imagefolder, LocationName);
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subImageFolder);


                using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    var uri = ("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&pithumbsize=400&titles="+name1);
                    var response = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(uri));
                    var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

                    var firstKey = responseJson.query.pages.First().Key;
                    string image1 = responseJson.query.pages[firstKey].thumbnail.source;
                    string Image_title = responseJson.query.pages[firstKey].title;
                    Image1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    Image1.LoadAsync(image1);
                    Image1_title.Text = Image_title;


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In form1.cs I call this class in the follwing way. and in Textbox I wrote the name such as Berlin.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1.Image1 = pictureBox1;
        Class1.Load_Image(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Text);
    }
```

I am not finding out what is the problem with this code

The json I got is

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"query": {
    "pages": {
        "3354": {
            "pageid": 3354,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Berlin",
            "thumbnail": {
                "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Siegessaeule_Aussicht_10-13_img4_Tiergarten.jpg/400px-Siegessaeule_Aussicht_10-13_img4_Tiergarten.jpg",
                "width": 400,
                "height": 267
            },
            "pageimage": "Siegessaeule_Aussicht_10-13_img4_Tiergarten.jpg"
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: var responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);  this line @Soner

Comment: Post the JSON that is returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output of your query, it says this:

> This is the HTML representation of the JSON format. HTML is good for debugging, but is unsuitable for application use.
>
> Specify the *format* parameter to change the output format. To see the non-HTML representation of the JSON format, set `format=json`.

If you follow that advice, it should fix your error.

Answer (score -1):

To display image from URL you need to use `WebClient` to load image in local system.

ie.

```
string remoteUri = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Siegessaeule_Aussicht_10-13_img4_Tiergarten.jpg/400px-Siegessaeule_Aussicht_10-13_img4_Tiergarten.jpg";
string fileName = "MyImage.jpg", 
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri,fileName);
```

Comment: I think you get JSON through web request. You need to perform another web request that will save image to local system. Please check my code.

Comment: I solved My problem. It was problem in my json request. Now I corrected it. Thank you @Bhavik